# How to "deploy" an HTML/CSS email signature?

Tags: email, outlook

I enjoy creating carefully crafted HTML/CSS e-mail signatures for my clients.

My current method for delivering these to clients is to e-mail them a URL, tell them to copy the contents of the web page (the signature), and paste it into the New Signature rich-text entry field of their e-mail client of choice. This sounds simple, but can lead to difficulty for the end user, which leads to a disproportionate amount of support time for me.

**Is there a better way to deliver e-mail signatures?**

The ideal solution would be to send a file that, when executed, would install the signature into their email client. A complete answer would provide steps for creating this in a cross-client way or through vendor-specific tools, if necessary.

I'm a programmer. The reason I posted this question on Stack Overflow is because I believe the solution to this may be to write some code. Which I'm okay with, if that's way it takes. I'm willing to put in whatever amount of work is necessary to make this process as easy as possible for as many different e-mail clients as possible.

I'm aware that for Microsoft Outlook users, I could be [delivering signatures in the Outlook Template File (.OFT) format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/outlook-e-mail-signature-samples-TC010186391.aspx). But as far as I can tell, this method would simply open a blank composition window with the signature inserted, which doesn't actually help them install it for future use.

Comment: It's a while since I worked with Outlook (and it was Outlook 2003), so the following advice may be erroneous; but doesn't it just pick up signature files from a certain folder (Somewhere in Application Data, I think)? If that is correct, you could either get the user to save a .rtf file to that folder, or write something to download/save the file there. If it does work that way, the user would just need to select the new signature from a list.

Comment: Also, whether my solution works or not, you will probably want to ensure that whatever you do leaves the customer with a plain text signature. I expect the GUI would normally take care of that automatically, but it's the sort of thing that wouldn't be immediately obvious if handled incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my win7 laptop its located in:
C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures

NSIS could be configured to 'install' files into this directory requiring little to no effort for your clients

**http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page**

Answer (score 0):

Using http://www.outlooksignatures.com you don't have to ask your clients for anything because it gives you the authority to design your client's outlook signatures without their participation. It will save you the support time because clients don't have to do anything. It allows you to change any given number of signatures in only a couple of minutes.